# Convolve doesn't yeild expected answer, nor does integrate

Tags: integral-equations, convolution

I am convolving, or trying to, a Gaussian and a Lorentzian as follows:

```
Gaussian1[ \[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_, x_] := 
1/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) Exp[-(1/2) ((x - \[Mu]) / \[Sigma])^2]

Lorentzian[\[Gamma]_, x0_, x_] := 
1/\[Pi] (1/2 \[Gamma])/((x - x0)^2 + (1/2 \[Gamma])^2)
```

The convolution attempt being

```
Convolve[Lorentzian[1, \[Gamma], x0, x], Gaussian1[1, \[Mu], \[Sigma], x], x, y]
```

However this simply returns itself except output formatted:

```
 (\[Gamma] Convolve[1/((x - x0)^2 + \[Gamma]^2/4), 
      E^(-((x - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))), x, y])/(2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(
     3/2) \[Sigma])
```

If I add assumptions,

```
Assumptions->Re[\[Gamma]] && Re[\[Sigma]]
```

The result is the same. I also tried to perform the convolution using `Integrate[]` as:

```
Integrate[
            1/\[Pi] (1/2 \[Gamma])/((\[Tau])^2 + (1/2 \[Gamma])^2) * 1/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) Exp[-(1/2) ((t - \[Tau]) / \[Sigma])^2],
            {\[Tau], -Infinity, +Infinity},
            Assumptions->Re[\[Gamma]] && Re[\[Sigma]] 
        ]
```

No joy! This convolution is well known as a [Voigt profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_profile) So it has a solution but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try recasting your formulae to the internal PDF distributions [`NormalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html) and [`CauchyDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CauchyDistribution.html).

```
Convolve[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, σ], x], 
 PDF[CauchyDistribution[a, b], x], x, y]
(* -(1/(2 Sqrt[2] π^(3/2) σ))
 I E^((-a^2 + (b - I y)^2 + 2 a (-I b + y))/(
  2 σ^2)) (E^((
     2 I a b)/σ^2) π Erfi[((a - I b - y) Sqrt[
       1/σ^2])/Sqrt[2]] - 
    E^((2 I b y)/σ^2) π Erfi[((a + I b - y) Sqrt[
       1/σ^2])/Sqrt[2]] - 
    E^((2 I a b)/σ^2) Log[a - I b - y] + 
    E^((2 I b y)/σ^2) Log[a + I b - y] - 
    E^((2 I b y)/σ^2) Log[-a - I b + y] + 
    E^((2 I a b)/σ^2) Log[-a + I b + y]) *)
```